# I want to apply the Harris corner Detection and compute the R matrix using eigenvalues?

Tags: image-processing

I'm trying to solve [this](https://wp.kntu.ac.ir/nasihatkon/teaching/cvug/s2018/cv-undergrad-final-Spring2018-key.pdf) question about "Harris Corner Detection" but without differentiation kernels using eigenvalues to compute R using formulas in this [article](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse576/06sp/notes/HarrisDetector.pdf):

But I don't know whether I should compute the eigenvalues considering just the highlighted region of the image or apply it to the whole image.

When I calculate the eigenvalues considering just the highlighted portion of the image. Then [these](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=%7B%7B%CE%BB%2C-5%2C-7%7D%2C%7B-4%2C%CE%BB-9%2C-12%7D%2C%7B-8%2C-11%2C%CE%BB-14%7D%7D) are too complex. Then If get such type of complex values then how to tackle them?

Kindly help me to solve this.

Comment: You cannot compute the Harris corner detector without using derivatives ("differentiation kernels").